# How to send parameters with GET request in Flutter using Dio or http

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to send a GET request to a back-end server with some parameters, and I have been getting the error:

> DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [500]

The parameters I am sending contains a boolean value and a double too. How can I successfully make this request. I have tried  so many answers on Stack Overflow but none worked for me.
Below is my code snippet:

```
Future<Converter> currencyConverter() async {
    String convertURL = baseURL + 'convert/currency/';

    String auth = await localpref.getString('access');

  //  FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
  //    "switch": _switch,
 //     "s_currency": senderCurrencyVal,
//      "r_currency": recieverCurrencyVal,
 //     "amount": amount
 //   });

    Map<String, dynamic> payload = {
      "switch": _switch, //boool
      "s_currency": senderCurrencyVal, // string
      "r_currency": recieverCurrencyVal, // string
      "amount": amount  //double
    };
    try {
      var res = await dio.get(convertURL,
          //data: formData,
          queryParameters: payload,
          options: Options(
              followRedirects: false,
              validateStatus: (status) {
                return status < 500;
              },
              headers: {
                "accept": "*/*",
                "Authorization": "Bearer $auth",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
              }));

      if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode <= 250) {
        print("Transfer Succeed");
        var respBody = res.data;

        Converter converter = converterFromJson(res.data);
        print(converter.result);
        return converter;
      } else {
        print(res);
        print("Else not successful");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

  }
```

Note: that am not in charge of the backend  and I am made to know it was developed with Djangom also I have tried both `dio.get` and `dio.request` but I got the same result, formdata doesn't work with GET when using Dio.

This request works well in postman.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you tried hitting same url in postman with same parameters ? is it working as expected there ?

Comment: Yest everything works fine in postman

Comment: Code seems fine. Is this the only request which is not working fine in your project ?

Comment: yes , my post and patch works fine and even get without parameter also works fine

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [how to fix it Data not showing in list in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958249/how-to-fix-it-data-not-showing-in-list-in-flutter/62959725#62959725).

I use http directly for any get.. Also check out https://app.quicktype.io/ to quickly create decoder classes. To use it copy the response from postman here and it will generate a class for you in Dart.

Comment: I created a class initially but it was always call on NULL as the api call does not  return anything

Comment: Also check out the url... There might be a / missing .. when you used concat

Comment: i have done  that, in fact the URL works fine without parameters, its when i add parameters , that i have that issue

Comment: Could you share the full link and sample fields i can try run it

Comment: Wait... To send data to receive response you have to use post() that's in http

Comment: thank you @king mort for your assistance , i later discovered that you cant post a data (formData) using dio you would have to use queryparams, but the Api was not accepting that , so i had to contact the backend engineer for the fix, my above code now works... sometimes you are less stress when you are full stack  :-)