# To post and get data, to or from server in flutter using http library

Tags: android, http, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am in new Flutter development, what I want to implement is :
To post data to the server from **A screen**, and wait for the response in **B screen**

example:
When a user types the words/keywords in the **Search Page**, I want to make a POST request and wait
for the response of that request in the **Result Page**

I am using library:
https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: could you add some more information on what you are trying to do and what you already tried?

Comment: @McSlinPlay, So far, I am making a post request from the **Search Page**, waiting for the response and then starting the **Result Page** along with passing the data to it as well and it's working fine. But what I want is, to make a request then go the **Result Page** and then wait there for the response.

Comment: Edit your post to include 1) What you have tried, 2) your Code for what you have tried so far, 3) Add more detail and show code where you are trying to post from and receive from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer on how to use http for API calls here. [how to fix it Data not showing in list in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958249/how-to-fix-it-data-not-showing-in-list-in-flutter/62959725#62959725)
To get the results on the second add the parameters you enter to the Route in navigation and execute the API call function in the second screen