# Flutter when comes first time on screen sharedpreferences value shows null

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

hello friends i really need your help ! i am working on project and i am stuck to get sharedPreferences value when page is load....! this is my photogallery project ! i have photlisting in that u can swipe left and right to see images..! now what is the problem is when i call api to get details... i can get data in my initState() i can see response but in that i can see isLike count is printed ** and saved in my isLike veriable which i Did you mean: declarer...! but when i go to set condition part for the color set !  the first time when page is open isLike is showing null...! but when i scroll i can get value....! what i need is when page is open i want value in **isLike** ! plz help me i will help u in code to understand

Can u show me any suggestions idea on my code

```
int index;
int isLike; /// here is my veribe
Future<PhotoDetail> pagedetail() async {
sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Map data = {
  "AccessToken": sharedPreferences.getString("AccessToken"),
  "CustomerId":  sharedPreferences.getInt("CustomerId"),
  "ImageId":   indexx == null ? widget.images[widget.currentindex].photoId : indexx
 };
 print(data);
final http.Response response = await http.post(
  Constants.CUSTOMER_WEBSERVICE_URL + "/photo/detail",
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(data),
);
var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {

  print("Response status : ${response.statusCode}");
  print("Response status : ${response.body}");

  isLike = jsonResponse["IsLike"]; //here i saving value when api is run
  print("iSLiked Value:" +isLike.toString());  // value is printing here
  return PhotoDetail.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

} else {

  throw Exception('Failed to load data');
 }
 }

 PageController _pageController;
 Future<FolderSummery> _futureSummary;
 List<Widget> imagefilter;



  @override
 void initState() {
 setState(() {
 pagedetail(); //here is my api run when page is load
 });
super.initState();
 imageid = widget.ImageId[index].photoId;
 _pageController = PageController(initialPage: widget.currentindex);
  print("like first time page load :" + isLike.toString()); //showing null isLike

  }


   void pageChange(int index){  //this method is when i scroll page 
   setState(() {
  pagedetail();  // api is call again and again
  indexx =  widget.images[index].photoId;
  print("When page change Like :" + isLike.toString()); //isLiked is printing here
  print("Image ID :" + indexx.toString()); 
  });
  }
  

    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
    leading: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 1,top: 5,bottom: 5),
      child: Container(
          height: 8,
          width: 35,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,color: Color(0xfff58634,),size: 40,),
            ),
          )
      ),
    ),
    title: Center(
        child: Text("Dhara Weds Bharat")
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20,top: 5,bottom: 5),
        child: Container(
            height: 8,
            width: 35,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list,color: Color(0xfff58634),size: 40,),
            )
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          child:
          Center(
              child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
                itemCount: widget.images.length,
                builder: (BuildContext context , int index) {
                  return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
                    imageProvider:
                    NetworkImage(widget.images[index].photoPreviewImagePath),
                    maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 1.8,
                    minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 1.0,
                  );
                },
                pageController:  _pageController,
                enableRotation: false,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                onPageChanged: pageChange,
                loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context , ImageChunkEvent event){
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                },
              )
          )
      ),
     
      Positioned(
        bottom: 10,
        left: 30,
        right: 30,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                child: InkWell(
                  child:  Icon(Icons.thumb_up,size: 20,color: isLike == 1 ? Color(0xfff58634) : 
           Colors.white), //HERE IS THE ISSUE WHEN I COME FIRST TIME VALUE IS NULL ! BUT WHEN SCROOLLING VALU IS PRINTING
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
             
                child:  Icon(Icons.comment,size: 20,color: Colors.white),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                child: Icon(Icons.share,size: 20,color: Colors.white,),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                child:  Icon(Icons.photo_album,size: 20,color: Colors.white,),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                child:  Icon(Icons.print,size: 20,color: Colors.white,),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                child:  Icon(Icons.card_giftcard,size: 20,color: Colors.white,),
              ),
            ]
        ),
      ),
     
    ],
   ),
   );
   }
```

DO U HAVE ANY TIPS PLZ EDIT MY CODE AND GIVE ME PROPER SOLUTION PLZ..

*API RESPONSE*

```
 import 'dart:convert';

 PhotoDetail photoDetailFromJson(String str) => PhotoDetail.fromJson(json.decode(str));

 String photoDetailToJson(PhotoDetail data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

 class PhotoDetail {
PhotoDetail({
this.successCode,
this.successMessage,
this.likeCount,
this.commentCount,
this.selectedCount,
this.isLike,
});

String successCode;
String successMessage;
int likeCount;
int commentCount;
int selectedCount;
int isLike;

factory PhotoDetail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PhotoDetail(
successCode: json["SuccessCode"],
successMessage: json["SuccessMessage"],
likeCount: json["LikeCount"],
commentCount: json["CommentCount"],
selectedCount: json["SelectedCount"],
isLike: json["IsLike"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
"SuccessCode": successCode,
"SuccessMessage": successMessage,
"LikeCount": likeCount,
"CommentCount": commentCount,
"SelectedCount": selectedCount,
"IsLike": isLike,
};
 }
```

Comment: sharedpreferences leads its data asynchronously so for a split second the value will be null. My suggestion would be to assign something to your variable or only execute the function if the value isn't null

Comment: can u give me in example ??

Comment: here's one way to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958249/how-to-fix-it-data-not-showing-in-list-in-flutter/62959725#62959725